# bootstrap popover positioning - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a login and register link where user can click and gets popover opened to login. I want that popover is a bit shifted to the left so that it hangs like this: 
[image]

i am on 15' Screen laptop, so far it is fine. But if i open in bigger resolution, it looks like this:

[image]

I am setting this in js like this:

```
$('#profilepover').on('shown.bs.popover', function(){
   $('.popover').css('left','774px');
});
```

how can I make it stick to login link no matter how big the screen is?

Comment: adjust your `left's` value with `%` like `.css('left','75%');`

Comment: @NikhilButani not working somehow.. it is possible to make it relative to ``login`` link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `left` use `right`:

```
$('#profilepover').on('shown.bs.popover', function(){
   $('.popover').css({right: '115px', left: 'auto'});
});
```

Right position will not change with window resize. Of course `115px` is just an example, adjust it to your actual layout. You also need to reset left position to `auto` in this case because default popover left is 0.

Comment: awesome, let me check this out

Comment: but, it is still having static right distance. if i adjust this for big screen, in small screens, it is going to left because of ``right`` :(, is it possible to make it relative to ``login`` link?

Comment: @doniyor Look at this example I set up, resize the window to see that popover stays on the right properly. http://plnkr.co/edit/z2y3aUzfxuOCrmy0d7kh?p=preview

Comment: wow thank you so much for this effort.. i think, my popover should be inside a container

Answer (score 1):

```
  $('#profilepover').on('shown.bs.popover', function(){
       var lft=$('#profilepover').position().left;
       $('.popover').css(left:lft);
    });
```

Try this out.. it works for me..